# How to achieve Polyglot with Prisma, MySQL, neo4j and redis?

Tags: mysql, neo4j, prisma, polyglot

I am using Prisma + MySQL in Production. Works great! There's a need in near future where we need to use neo4j alongside/completely. Any suggestions on can we achieve this with the existing artifacts, as apparently Prisma doesn't support neo4j. So if we can continue using Prisma or we stop using it and start using neo4j orm.

Answer (score 1):

Prisma doesn't currently support neo4j, though there are plans to add support in the future. Polyglot support is a use case that Prisma is targeting at large. You can follow the development status in the [Github issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma2/issues/1575) ( to signal your interest).

In the meanwhile, I'd suggest looking at neo4j specific abstractions.

The Node.js ecosystem there is the [neo4j driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver) and an OGM (Object Graph Mapper) called [Neode](https://github.com/adam-cowley/neode)